# Getting "ImportError: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file" when importing OpenCV

Tags: python, linux, opencv

I'm having trouble importing OpenCV.

Environment:

- Python 3.6.1
- Linux (HPC server)
- OpenCV 3.4.3.18

Error Description:

I'm trying to import `cv2` after a successful installation (`Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /home/users/czxu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (3.4.3.18)`) with command: `import cv2`, but it seems that a folder or script is missing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/preprocessing/gen_mini_batches.py", line 4, in <module>
    from avod.builders.dataset_builder import DatasetBuilder
  File "/home/users/czxu/avod/avod/builders/dataset_builder.py", line 6, in <module>
    from avod.datasets.kitti.kitti_dataset import KittiDataset
  File "/home/users/czxu/avod/avod/datasets/kitti/kitti_dataset.py", line 11, in <module>
    from wavedata.wavedata.tools.core import calib_utils
  File "/home/users/czxu/avod/wavedata/wavedata/tools/core/calib_utils.py", line 3, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/home/users/czxu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
srun: error: sh-06-20: task 0: Exited with exit code 1
```

I went to the folder `/home/users/czxu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/`

```
czxu@cv2$cd /home/users/czxu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2
czxu@cv2$ls -a
.  ..  cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  data  __init__.py  .libs  LICENSE-3RD-PARTY.txt  LICENSE.txt  __pycache__
```

Do you have any idea about this? Answers and discussions will be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 38):

Had the same problem (Python 3.6.6, opencv 3.4.3.18, Ubuntu 18.04). I fixed it by installing libXrender:

```
sudo apt-get install libxrender1
```

This was documented [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-wkhtmltopdf-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libxrender-so-1/). After installing, I am able to `import cv2`.

Comment: I don't have root access. Any other workaround?

Answer (score 1):

```
yum -y install libSM-1.2.2-2.el7.x86_64 --setopt=protected_multilib=false
yum -y install libXext-1.3.3-3.el7.x86_64 --setopt=protected_multilib=false
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26235090)

Comment: I am using CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core) with Linux 3.10.0-1160.36.2.el7.x86_64  and it says that these libraries already installed.

Answer (score 0):

For CentOS and RHEL:

`yum install libXrender`

It can be verified by the following command that shows the needed packages (in different versions):

`yum whatprovides libXrender`

For other missed `libX*.so` works the same package naming convention