# ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("jpg"); throws UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, adoptopenjdk

I'm trying to run some code locally in a Windows machine using `WSL/Ubuntu` with `openjdk version "21.0.2"`. The code reads a `.jpg` image, but fails specifically at this step:

```
ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("jpg");
```

This line throws an Error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/user/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.10-tem/lib/libawt_xawt.so: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to change the format name to `jpeg`, `JPG` and `JPEG` with the same results.

This code runs with no problems on a MacOS and a Windows physical system. It runs on Linux containers as well.

I tried to reinstall Java with no luck.

Edit: I tried already [sudo apt-get install libxrender1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52547833/getting-importerror-libxrender-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-when-impo) with no luck. Now this question is closed without any feedback on how to improve the quality of the question...

Edit 2: Writing my solution here for the ages since I was blocked from getting answers to my question witout any piece of feedback.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77130159/3128369) with the solution:

- Install libxrender1 - `sudo apt-get install libxrender1`
- Modify the file ~/.bashrc to add:

  export DISPLAY=:0
  export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority
- Run `source ~/.bashrc`

That led me to another error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/daniel-fuente/user/candidates/java/17.0.10-tem/lib/libawt_xawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
```

Then I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/843434) that led me to the end of the solution:

```
apt-get install libxrender1 libxtst6 libxi6
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "ImportError: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file" when importing OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52547833/getting-importerror-libxrender-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-when-impo)

Comment: No, it does not work  @tgdavies